# What does a 'P' in a graphite graph mean?

Tags: graphite

What does the 'P' in front of the values on the Y axis mean in graphite?

[image: Graphite Values]

Comment: Um, depends on what the Y axis represents?

Comment: Pita chips, is my guess.

Comment: I think the green line represents a trend in the number of Proper questions in SF.

Comment: This question would be a whole lot more useful/answerable if you told us what was being graphed, rather than just a shot of the Y axis. Please update your question with more details and it may get reopened.

Comment: The numerical value is independent of what is being graphed its just an value. Thx @jgoldsschrafe for correct answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"P" is the abbreviation for the SI prefix "peta", or 10^15.